# Apache HTTP Server - .htaccess versioning

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, version

I'm trying to implement the versioning of my static site using the Apache Server and its .htaccess file.
The directive for rewriting the path to the version folder is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/1.0.20/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /1.0.20/$1 [L]
```

I want to know what pitfalls can be and is this a decent decision at all?

P.S. Searches in the Internet of such a decision were unsuccessful.

Comment: Depends...on which OS are you ? If you're on UNIX like, you should probably use symbolic links instead.

Comment: @AndreGelinas im on linux. Please tell me what you mean?

Comment: Something like, if your DocumentRoot value is mydocroot then create a SymLink from mydocroot to 1.0.20. Whenever Apache will try to access mydocroot, it will be in 1.0.20. If you upgrade, you change the symlink from mydocroot to say 1.0.30. No reboot necessary, easy rollback.

Comment: @AndreGelinas I'm currently using hosting, and it feels like I might not have access to such functionality. And tell me please, what is the advantage of symlinks? Speed or something else?

Comment: Simpler than rewriting. Anyway, then unless you have several virtual host (other than www.example, you dont need the second rule and I would use : RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /1.0.20/$1 [PT] instead (which is more or less the equivalent of the Alias directive which I'm not sure works well in an htaccess file). Still need to be tested as I'm not using htaccess myself.

Comment: @AndreGelinas Do you mean that I can delete the second line and replace the third line with the one you specified?
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/1.0.20/
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /1.0.20/$1 [PT]`
Can you clarify the role of [L] and [PT] flags?

Comment: L means that it is the last rule for those condition, PT means that it is to be considered a passtrough (like Alias). You might want to read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: @AndreGelinas Please answer the first question, about the corrections of the rewriting directive?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @AndreGelinas thanks!

Comment: @AndreGelinas This rule does not work: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /1.0.20/$1 [PT]`.
And this works: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /1.0.20/$1 [L]`.
This can be removed in my case, you were right: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.`. I do not use `www`.